# C# reference to the desktop

Tags: c#, special-folders

I am using a file stream to write out a file.

I was hoping to be able to write the file to the desktop.

If I have something like

```
tw = new StreamWriter("NameOflog file.txt");
```

I would like to be able to have some sort of @desktop identified in front of the file name that would automatically insert the path to the desktop.

Does this exist in C#? Or do I have to look for desktop paths on a computer by computer (or OS by OS) basis?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Quick google search reveals this one:

```
string strPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(
                         System.Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
```

**EDIT**: This will work for Windows, but [Mono supports it](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=T%3ASystem.Environment.SpecialFolder), too.

Comment: Note that according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx this will only work on Windows, so for other OS, you might check if it works first.

Comment: @schnaader: I do believe it also works on Mono/Linux (it should return "/home/username/desktop").

Comment: @Noldorin: Thanks for this note, I finally found a link about Mono and Environment.SpecialFolder here: http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=T%3ASystem.Environment.SpecialFolder

Answer (score 10):

You want to use [Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getfolderpath.aspx), passing in [`SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx).

There's also `SpecialFolder.Desktop` which represents the *logical* desktop location - it's not clear what the difference between the two is though.

Comment: Holy cow, Jon Skeet was beat to the punch. Jon, you're not losing your edge on us, are ya buddy? :)

Comment: I was busy looking up the links :(

Comment: Come on Jon, you're supposed to have this stuff memorized by now :)

Comment: The difference may have to do with folder redirection via group policy. Perhaps the SpecialFolder.Desktop refers to the actual location of the folder instead of its normal path on the hard drive

Comment: ...like in setups where your Desktop is stored in your profile, which is then actually physically located up on a central server?

Comment: It appears "logical" might equal "virtual" in the case of `SpecialFolder.Desktop`'s description; see here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494(VS.85).aspx

I think `DesktopDirectory` is the one to use.

Answer (score 9):

Something like:

```
string logPath = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),
    "NameOflog file.txt");
tw = new StreamWriter(logPath);
```

Answer (score 3):

You want Environment.SpecialFolder

```
string fileName = "NameOflog file.txt";
path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), fileName);
tw = new StreamWriter(path);
```

Answer (score 2):

yep.
you can use environmental variables.
like

```
tw = new StreamWriter("%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\mylogfile.txt");
```

but i would not recommend to automatically write a log file to the users desktop.
you should add the link to the file to your start menu folder.
or even populate them  in the event log. (much better)

Answer (score 1):

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory))
```

Answer (score 1):

I also use the method mentioned above.

But here are a couple different options that work too (just to have a more comprehensive list):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
  // 1st way
  private const int MAX_PATH = 260;
  private const int CSIDL_DESKTOP = 0x0000;
  private const int CSIDL_COMMON_DESKTOPDIRECTORY = 0x0019; // Can get to All Users desktop even on .NET 2.0,
                                                            // where Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory is not available
  [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
  private static extern bool SHGetSpecialFolderPath(IntPtr hwndOwner, StringBuilder lpszPath, int nFolder, bool fCreate);
  static string GetDesktopPath()
  {
    StringBuilder currentUserDesktop = new StringBuilder(MAX_PATH);
    SHGetSpecialFolderPath((IntPtr)0, currentUserDesktop, CSIDL_DESKTOP, false);
    return currentUserDesktop.ToString();
  }

  // 2nd way
  static string YetAnotherGetDesktopPath()
  {
    Guid PublicDesktop = new Guid("C4AA340D-F20F-4863-AFEF-F87EF2E6BA25");
    IntPtr pPath;

    if (SHGetKnownFolderPath(PublicDesktop, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out pPath) == 0)
    {
      return System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pPath);
    }

    return string.Empty;
  }
}
```

Then:

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(GetDesktopPath(), "NameOfLogFile.txt");
```